# Get lengths of intermediate concatenated files in ffmpeg filter-complex

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, metadata, tableofcontents, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm writing a media Electron app that occasionally needs to individually trim => individually normalize => concatenate => convert a varying number of WAV files into MP3.
I've successfully used FFMPEG (via Fluent-ffmpeg) to do so (command wrapped for visibility):

```
ffmpeg -i 3.301_to_8.752_Careful.wav -i 8.752_to_18.751_Careful.wav -y 
-filter_complex 
[0]silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=-50dB[mid];[mid]loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11[out];
[1]silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=-50dB[mid];[mid]loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11[b];
[out][b]concat=v=0:a=1[out]
 -b:a 128k -ac 1 -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 -map [out] -y Careful_Merged.mp3
```

Here's the relevant parts of the output:

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono
Input #0, wav, from '3.301_to_8.752_Careful.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:05.50, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, wav, from '8.752_to_18.751_Careful.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:10.30, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 705 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le) -> silenceremove
  Stream #1:0 (pcm_s16le) -> silenceremove
  concat -> Stream #0:0 (libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to 'Careful_Merged.mp3':
  Metadata:
    TSSE            : Lavf58.28.101
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.53.101 libmp3lame
size=     246kB time=00:00:15.69 bitrate= 128.4kbits/s speed=33.8x
video:0kB audio:246kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.170563%
```

The benefit is that the process chains nicely, but the downside is that I don't know the resulting length of the intermediate files after the automagic trim. My app needs a "table of contents" showing the start and end of each segment, but I can't figure out how to export the duration of each trimmed file before concatenation between
[`0]silenceremove=start_periods=1:start_threshold=-50dB[mid];[mid]loudnorm=I=-16:TP=-1.5:LRA=11[out]` and the concatenation `[out][b]concat=v=0:a=1[out]`.

It's so elegant as it is, I'd prefer not to save the intermediate files to disk or trim the audio twice to get the info I need. All I need is a duration for each, and I can do the math.
Is there a filter that I can put inline to export the intermediate duration, or a way to get a log of the concatenation action?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the command with `-loglevel verbose` or `-v 40`, concat will log segment EOF events with timings in microseconds e.g.

```
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 00000000037e3440] EOF on in0:v0, 0 streams left in segment.
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 00000000037e3440] Segment finished at pts=5500000
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 00000000037e3440] EOF on in1:v0, 0 streams left in segment.
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 00000000037e3440] Segment finished at pts=6533333
```

The first segment was 5.5s long, and the 2nd was 6533333 us - 5500000 us = 1.03s long.

Comment: Awesome! I had tried several different logging levels (mainly debug), but didn't recognize that "pts" was what I needed in milliseconds. Now I just need to catch and parse the log via fluent-ffmpeg. Thanks!